# Terminal does not open current directory on vscode

Tags: gnome-terminal, visual-studio-code

I am using Pop_Os 20.04 and i am newbie. the problem is terminal does not open current directory while launching vscode. I had no such issue like this a few days ago i do not know how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra dot :)
This opens the directory above your current one.